# How to grep and execute a command (for every match)

Tags: grep

How to grep in one file and execute for every match a command?

File:

```
foo
bar
42
foo
bar
```

I want to execute to execute for example `date` for every match on `foo`.

Following try doesn't work:

```
grep file foo | date %s.%N
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
grep file foo | while read line ; do echo "$line" | date %s.%N ; done
```

More readably in a script:

```
grep file foo | while read line
do
    echo "$line" | date %s.%N
done
```

For each line of input, `read` will put the value into the variable `$line`, and the `while` statement will execute the loop body between `do` and `done`. Since the value is now in a variable and not stdin, I've used `echo` to push it back into stdin, but you could just do `date %s.%N "$line"`, assuming date works that way.

Avoid using `` for line in `grep file foo` `` which is similar, because `for` always breaks on spaces and this becomes a nightmare for reading lists of files:

```
 find . -iname "*blah*.dat" | while read filename; do ....
```

would fail with `for`.

Comment: No problem. There are unix tools for most bulk tasks, including things like grep's ability to read multiple patterns from a file (-f), or xargs's ability to construct commands from stdin.

Comment: Should this not be:

    grep foo file
    
-------

NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

Comment: how can I execute the script: 
grep file foo | while read line
do
    echo "$line" | date %s.%N
done
Do I need to put in a file?

Comment: @EsNoguera you can if you want to. You can run it on the command line by putting `;` between lines, like `grep file foo | while read line; do echo "$line" | date %s.%N; done`. To run any commands (including that) from a file just put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file (I'd run `which bash` to find out where your bash lives), paste in the commands, save it and mark it executable: `chmod +x <scriptfile>`.

Comment: To execute the match immediately, do something like `./test.sh | tee /dev/tty | stdbuf -o0 egrep '(foo|bar)' |while read line; do echo "FOUND $line"; done`

Comment: This is broken; `date` does not read anything from standard input.

Comment: Does not work with nano: `grep -lir "file.txt" | while read line ; do echo "$line" | nano ; done` Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
Buffer written to nano.save.2

Answer (score 25):

What you really need is a **xargs** command. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

```
grep file foo | xargs date %s.%N
```

example of matching some files and converting matches to the full windows path in Cygwin environment

```
$ find $(pwd) -type f -exec ls -1 {} \; | grep '\(_en\|_es\|_zh\)\.\(path\)$' | xargs cygpath -w
```

Comment: Does not work with nano: `grep -lir "file.txt" | xargs nano`
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

Answer (score 7):

```
grep command_string file | sh -
```

Comment: why doesn't this work without the trailing hypen (-)? In contrast, `echo hello | cat -` is equivalent to `echo hello | cat` at least in my shell.

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting command in linux for that: **`xargs`**, It allows You to use the output from previous command(grep, ls, find, etc.) as the input for a custom execution but with several options that allows You to even execute the custom command in parallel. Below some examples:

Based in your question, here is how to print the date with format "**%s.%N**" for each "**foo**" match in file.txt:

```
grep "foo" file.txt | xargs -I {} date +%s.%N
```

A more interesting use is creating a file for each match, but in this case if matches are identical the file will be override:

```
grep "foo" file.txt | xargs -I {} touch {}
```

If You want to concatenate a custom date to the file created

```
grep "foo" file.txt | xargs -I {} touch "{}`date +%s.%N`"
```

Imagine the matches are file names and You want to make a backup of them:

```
grep "foo" file.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} "{}.backup"
```

And finally for xargs using the custom date in the backupName

```
grep "foo" file.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} "{}`date +%s.%N`"
```

For more info about options like parallel execution of **xargs** visit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs and for date formats: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/date-command-examples/

Extra I have found also a normal for command useful in this scenarios It is simpler but less versatile below are the equivalent for above examples:

```
for i in `grep "foo" test.txt`; do date +%s.%N; done
for i in `grep "foo" test.txt`; do touch ${i}; done
for i in `grep "foo" test.txt`; do touch "${i}`date +%s.%N`"; done
for i in `grep "foo" test.txt`; do cp ${i} "${i}.backup2"; done
for i in `grep "foo" test.txt`; do cp ${i} "${i}.backup2`date +%s.%N`"; done
```

Have Fun!!!

Answer (score 1):

grep may need `--line-buffered` option to emit each matching line when it matches it, otherwise it buffers up to 4K byte before printing match lines, which defeats the goal here, e.g.

```
tail -f source | grep --line-buffered "expression | xargs ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    grep search_string files_to_search | sh
```