# Oneline file-monitoring

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I have a logfile continously filling with stuff.

I wish to monitor this file, grep for a specific line and then extract and use parts of that line in a curl command.

I had a look at [How to grep and execute a command (for every match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402119/how-to-grep-and-execute-a-command-for-every-match)

This would work in a script but I wonder if it is possible to achieve this with the oneliner below using xargs or something else?

**Example:**

```
Tue May 01|23:59:11.012|I|22|Event to process : [imsi=242010800195809, eventId = 242010800195809112112, msisdn=4798818181, inbound=false, homeMCC=242, homeMNC=01, visitedMCC=238, visitedMNC=01, timestamp=Tue May 12 11:21:12 CEST 2015,hlr=null,vlr=4540150021, msc=4540150021 eventtype=S, currentMCC=null, currentMNC=null teleSvcInfo=null camelPhases=null serviceKey=null gprsenabled= false APNlist: null SGSN: null]|com.uws.wsms2.EventProcessor|processEvent|139
```

**Extract the fields I want and semi-colon separate them:**

```
tail -f file.log | grep "Event to process" | awk -F'=' '{print $2";"$4";"$12}' | tr -cd '[[:digit:].\n.;]'
```

Curl command, e.g. something like:

```
http://user:pass@www.some-url.com/services/myservice?msisdn=...&imsi=...&vlr=...
```

Thanks!

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to read values line-by-line and field-by-field. Then use those to do what you want in the loop.

Comment: Clean-up: replace everything from `grep` onwards with one command: `awk -F'=' '/Event to process/{$0=$2";"$4";"$12; gsub(/[^[:digit:].;]/,""); print}'`. I removed the `\n`, and the 2nd `.` from the `tr` as they would do nothing.

Comment: I left the grep etc. as the solution above works fine in Linux but not with Solaris. I believe it's just quotes but then again I didn't try .. The complete answer is then: `tail -f file.log | grep "Event to process" | awk -F'=' '{print $2";"$4";"$12}' | tr -cd '[[:digit:].\n.;]' | while IFS=";" read -r imsi msisdn vlr; do echo "IMSI is: $imsi"; echo "MSISDN is: $msisdn"; echo "VLR is: $vlr"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tail -f file.log | grep "Event to process" | awk -F'=' '{print $2" "$4" "$12; }' | tr -cd '[[:digit:].\n. ]' |while read msisdn imsi vlr ; do curl "http://user:pass@www.some-url.com/services/myservice?msisdn=$msisdn&imsi=$imsi&vlr=$vlr" ; done
```