# How to grep and execute command for every multiline match

Tags: bash, grep

Is there the possibility to process a multiline grep-output by one command each?

I've got something like

```
<fulldata>
<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>
</fulldata>
<fulldata>
<value>2</value>
<value>3</value>
</fulldata>
```

and want to get means, standard deviation and do some other things with data-element on its own.

In this case, I want to execute

```
function printStatistics {
        mean1=$(awk -F ';' '{print $1}' $1 | awk '{sum += $1; square += $1^2} END {print sum / NR}')
        deviation1=$(awk -F ';' '{print $1}' $1 | awk '{sum += $1; square += $1^2} END {print sqrt(square / NR - (sum/NR)^2)}')
        size=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
        echo $mean1 $deviation1 $size
}
```

with the expected result (for the sample data), idealy separated by newline:

```
1,5 0,7 2
2,5 0,7 2
```

Running

```
cat add.xml | grep "<fulldata" -A 2001 | while read line ; do echo "Line: $line" ; done
```

like suggested in [How to grep and execute a command (for every match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402119/how-to-grep-and-execute-a-command-for-every-match) does result in one entry for each line; but I want one entry for each entry (in order to execute `awk` stuff on it later).

Is this possible with grep, or is this a use case where another language would be more appropriate?

Comment: That's XML, not a line-oriented data format. Use a proper XML parser, not `grep`.

Comment: *to get means, standard deviation and do some other things* - post the expected result

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to parse html/xml with grep, because its not reliable.  If you are using Mac OS X, you can use a preinstalled cli tool called `xmllint` to select specific elements.  On linux, you can use the standard package manager to get it.

There is also [xgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xgrep), and probably others that I dont know about.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='\n?</?fulldata>\n' -F'\n' '
        !(NR%2){gsub("</?value>",""); 
                s=ss=0; 
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {s+=$i; ss+=$i^2} 
                printf "%.1f %.1f %d\n", s/NF, sqrt((ss-s^2/NF)/(NF-1)), NF} ' file

1.5 0.7 2
2.5 0.7 2
```

for the sample standard deviation as computed you need to guard for single observation (NF==1) case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! While this is very close to a solution, it returns `0.0 0.0 2` for every `fulldata`-entry. This is because the <value> is still present in the result line. If you write `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,result,">"); s+=result[2]; ss+=result[2]^2` as 4th line, it works (in my examples).

Comment: `gsub` should remove those. Perhaps your awk does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Complex `xmlstarlet` + `awk` solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//fulldata/value" -x "concat(.,',')" add.xml \
| xmlstarlet sel -B -t -v "//fulldata" -n \
| awk -F, '{ n=NF-1; sum=sq=0; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) { sum+=$i; sq+=$i^2 }
  printf "%.1f\n%.1f\n%d\n", sum/n, sqrt((sq-sum^2/n)/(n-1)), n }'
```

The output:

```
1.5
0.7
2
2.5
0.7
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This works. If you change the `printf "%.1f\n%.1f\n%d\n"` to `printf "%.1f %.1f %d\n"` it has exactly the format (which in my case is more usefull for analysis of the results, e.g. for plotting all means with gnuplot).

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt, welcome, the current format was chosen according to your phrase *idealy separated by newline:*